# JavaScript window not opening on New server

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Master page web application.  In that application I have the need for a popup window to open displaying several links.  The window should open when the user selects a value from a drop down list.  Both the below methods work fine when running the site locally in VS2010 and on the Dev server.  When moving to the UAT server it no longer fires and give no error.  If I replace the web config file on UAT with the one from Dev it fires correctly.  However when I update the web config file so it directs the connection strings to the UAT server it breaks. I have tried the below methods;

This is code used in other parts of the site and continues to work correctly

```
protected void ddCFPBCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,      EventArgs e) 
{
  if (this.ddCFPBCategories.SelectedValue.ToString() == "3rd Party Bad     Phone")
  {
 String csname1 = "myWindow";
 System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder("var winRef =      window.open('BadPhone.aspx',null,'width=900,height=400, status=yes,  resizeable=no, scrollbars=no,menubar=no');");
            Type cType = this.GetType();

            if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cType, csname1))
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cType, csname1,                           sb.ToString(), true);
            }
        }

    }
```

Here I try to use javascript onchange 
this is in the

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddCFPBCategories" runat="server"
                DataSourceID="ComplaintType" DataTextField="Descriptoin"
                DataValueField="Descriptoin" onchange="javascript:dypopup(this,'3rd Party Bad Phone','BadPhone.aspx',700,300,'yes','no','no','no')" >

            </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is in the Site.master:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function dypopup(ddl,testvalue,url,w,h,status,resize,scroll,menu) {
        if (ddl.value == testvalue)
        {
            window.open(url, null, 'width='+ w +',height='+ h +', status='+   status +', resizeable=' + resize +', scrollbars=' + scroll +',menubar=' + menu   +"'")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting a client side error if you check your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: mason thanks for your reply.  I found the issue and it was data related.  The objects in the panel were not populating.  It wasn't panel code after all.  all the best.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it was data related. The objects in the panel were not populating. It wasn't panel code after all.